# deploy multiple RESTful service bundles in ServiceMix/FUSE 4.3

Tags: rest, apache-servicemix

I am using the example cxf-jaxrs shipped with apache-servicemix-4.3.0-fuse-03-00.tar.gz to investigate how to deploy multiple bundles which provides different RESTful services. What I did is copied the cxf-jaxrs example into cxf-jaxrs-example-1, and modified the pom.xml and beans.xml. The modifications are :

```
1. pom.xml
version: 4.3.0-2-fuse-03-00
name: Apache ServiceMix Example 2:: CXF JAX-RS OSGI
2. beans.xml
<jaxrs:server id="customerService2" address="/crm2">
```

Then I made two packages. The one is the original example package cxf-jaxrs-4.3.0-fuse-03-00.jar and the other is the modified one cxf-jaxrs-4.3.0-2-fuse-03-00.jar and I copied them into "deploy" directory.

After servicemix started, I see both bundles are active and started succesfully.

But, I am only able to access the RESTful services in one bundle. When I type "http://localhost:8080/cxf/crm2/customerservice/customers/123", I got "No service was found." error. And when I stop the other example bundle(the original one), I can access "http://localhost:8080/cxf/crm2/customerservice/customers/123" with no problems.

What I did wrong?? It is supposed to provides the RESTful services in both context path "/crm" and "/crm2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem sovled. My bad. I forgot to modify the path annotation on CustomerService class